# Pastebin like apps for local install

Tags: pastebin

Are there any webapps that I can use as a company internal pastebin (I want to install on a local server)? The only requirement is syntax highlighting. I'm aware of the list on wikipedia, but maybe there are some new, not listed or whatever.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_pastebins

Comment: The Wikipedia page has been deleted.

Answer (score 1):

You can try php-pastebin:

Github: https://github.com/atmoner/php-pastebin-v3/
Demo: http://demo.php-pastebin.com/
Website: http://php-pastebin.com/